# translating bash functions to eshell

Tags: eshell, bash

Try to move to eshell and I am wondering what the best solution to translating the bash functions like below to eshell?

```bash
function cm-gen {
    cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON $@
    if [[ ! -e ./compile_commands.json && -e ./build/compile_commands.json ]]; then
        ln -s ./build/compile_commands.json .
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to take the meat of your function and place it into it's own non-eshell script; placing the script in a directory in your `$PATH`. If your command doesn't share a name with an *eshell* `alias`, *eshell* `builtin`, or *emacs* `function`; your script will be called.

From the [Eshell manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Invocation):

> Eshell looks first for an alias (see Aliases) with the same name as
> the command, then a built-in (see Built-in commands) or a function
> with the same name; if there is no match, it then tries to execute it
> as an external command.

If you are wondering what Emacs / Eshell considers an `external command`, I'm not sure of where a definitive answer lies (possibly [esh-mode.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/eshell/esh-mode.el)?). That said, Eshell can't use an external shell function directly (as in `source`d from `.bashrc` or somesuch) because said functions are directly embedded in the external shell state and Eshell doesn't try to do any kind of gymnastics to pull said functions into Emacs state.

The safest naive definition, from my experience, is any command that exists in the external shell's `$PATH`.

Also check out [this post](https://masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell) from [Mastering Emacs](https://masteringemacs.org).

All that said...maybe I didn't really answer your question?

The way that you'd "translate a bash function into eshell" would be to *translate the bash function into Elisp*. Eshell is a shell written in Elisp living inside Emacs...so it's a specialized Elisp interpreter.